# Django rendering an uploaded image on html

Tags: python, html, django, amazon-s3

I have stored some images in an amazon s3 bucket and I want to render them on html.

I am using this:

```
 <"{% static 'appname/path_to_image/%s' % {{article1.image}} %}">
```

But the problem is it won't consider the image url string but it takes the %s literally. How do I alter this in order for the article1.image url to become a part of the main url?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just give <img src="{{article1.image.url}}">

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Amazon S3 as Django’s storage and `article1.image` is an object of `ImageField` or `FileField`, you can obtain the image URL with `article1.image.url`.

So, you can use the URL in templates like this:

```
<img src="{{article1.image.url}}">
```

For more details, see [FileField.url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url) (`ImageField` inherits from `FileField`)